# Search student record without search button

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I wanted to display all student records from my sql db in vs form or datagridview just after typing the unique id of the student and not pressing any button for it. Can i create a search like above mentioned?

Comment: yes.what have you thought/done so far ?what db and front end are you using ?

Comment: I am using Sql server 14 and Visual studio 13 and was not able to find any article related to the topic so thought would ask here so no progress yet.

Comment: learn json, jquery autocomplete

Comment: [**`TextBox.TextChanged`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check [This!](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-and-Filter-GridView-as-you-type-in-TextBox-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx), This is exactly what you want